# Проблемы с подключением CSS

Tags: python, html, css, django

Писал небольшое web приложение на `Django`, но возникла проблема с полючением стилей.
Например `index.html`:

```
...

      {% load static %}
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/stylesheet.css' %}" type="text/css">
...
```

При открытии страницы в `sources.css` файл загружается, однако сама страница его не использует, то есть стили не применяются.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Структура проекта.

```
--Project

----base_app
------// Главное приложение

----Calendar // Другое приложение
------static
--------css
----------stylesheet.css
```

Comment: Попробуйте размещать папку static не в проекте Calendar а в проекте Project там где у вас файл manage.py . Так как скорее всего у вас в settings.py указано STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static') где BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Пробема была в том что я запихал этот CSS файл куда только можно было, и поэтому происходил какой то конфликт имен. Единственно верное решения на тот момент было все почистить от всех файлов стилей и добавить их только туда, куда нужно (в папку статик) после чего подгрузить при помощи load static

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте папку static разместить в папке проекта, а не приложения. Перед этим пропишите: `STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'static')` | BASE_DIR - это каталог проекта(находится в одной папке с manage.py) `BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent`